# Prove or disprove $ab\mid ac\Longrightarrow b\mid c$

Tags: number-theory

I need to prove or to give a counter-example:

> $$ab\mid ac\Longrightarrow b\mid c$$

**My attempt:**

Yes, this is correct, let's divide $ab$ and $ac$ by $a$ (assuming that $a\neq 0$) we get $$b\mid c$$ and that's it.

Is my attempt correct?

Comment: Your attempt is right.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat ok, thank you

Comment: It depends on the used definition of "divides". $(0\cdot 2) \mid (0\cdot 3)$ is a counterexample for the definition $u \mid v \iff (\exists w)(v = u\cdot w)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer so it will be correct only if $a\neq 0$?

Comment: I don't think you can say "let's divide $ab$ and $ac$ by $a$", because the task is**precisely** to prove that you can do that. Your "proof" is actually circular reasoning.

Comment: Depends on the setting. In $\mathbb{Z}$ - more generally in an integral domain - $a\neq 0$ is the condition that makes the inference work. If we have zero divisors, things are more complicated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Your attempt is correct. Let me simplify it.

**Proof:**

Assuming $a$ is not 0.

$$ab|ac \implies kab = ac \implies kb = c \implies b|c$$

Comment: Nice and simple

Comment: Provided that $a\neq 0$, see the comment of @Daniel Fischer.